# Can't use vcpkg on linux

Tags: c++, cmake, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Here is my `CMakelists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0) 
SET(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "/home/xxx/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake")
project(test)

find_package(unofficial-sqlite3 CONFIG REQUIRED)

add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE unofficial::sqlite3::sqlite3)
```

I'm trying to use vcpkg through `SET(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE ${vcpkg_root})`,but it seems that it doesn't work.Here is the error:

```
[cmake] CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package):
[cmake]   Could not find a package configuration file provided by
[cmake]   "unofficial-sqlite3" with any of the following names:
[cmake] 
[cmake]     unofficial-sqlite3Config.cmake
[cmake]     unofficial-sqlite3-config.cmake
```

I have verify that `unofficial-sqlite3-config.cmake` does exists in

```
/home/xxx/vcpkg/packages/sqlite3_x64-linux/share/unofficial-sqlite3/unofficial-sqlite3-config.cmake
```

I'm using WSL and vscode as IDE, Now I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Are you really using CMake 3.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not reproduce your issue using the following basic CMakeLists.txt

```makefile
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)
project(test)

find_package(unofficial-sqlite3 REQUIRED)

add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE unofficial::sqlite3::sqlite3)
```

I installed sqlite3 via `vcpkg install sqlite3` and ran the build via

```
$ echo 'int main() { return 0; }' > main.cpp
$ cmake -G Ninja -S . -B build -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=$VCPKG_ROOT/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.4.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Failed
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /path/to/build
```

As you can see, this worked flawlessly. I'm not sure whether setting your CMake policy level to the downright *ancient* 3.0 is what matters, or if you're using an old vcpkg checkout (I used the most recent commit at time of writing).

Comment: Actually, I found that the problem locates in the setting in VSCode. When I finally solve it by using Clion and setting the configuration of vcpkg.